# Backpack laravel how show in the same view tables related

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Hello how are you all? i enter here because i not found the reply in the documentation, i have a relation 1-1 in my ddbb, is there some way to show this linked in the same view crud? Then with a button that open the eloquent model related in a dialog. Or something in this way without load in. New windows reload, or by example show the details of the parent eloquent and show just in the line down tabulated the children table, there are some. Example that how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you ask if something like this is possible?

Controller:

```
$blogpost= Blogpost::where('id', '=', $id)
            ->with('comments')
            ->with('reactions')->first();

return view('blogpost_single','blogpost' => $blogpost);
```

Then in your view you can access the blogpost variable itself:

```
Blog title: {{$blogpost->title}}
```

and the children

```
Blog comment 1: {{$blogpost->comments[0]->text}} 
Blog comment 2: {{$blogpost->comments[1]->text}}
```

Comment: Yes, just this but only i have a children, and the children have a foreign key to father, i encode the relation in the eloquent model children

Comment: But not exactly in this way i am using backpack, then i add a controller/request/update model for adapte crud operations to this library, and i dont know how to do, in the base for eloquent model is just in the way that you show here, but i dont know how to do passing for the model/request/controller from. Backpack, i see examples only from isolates models with no relations or relations 1_n and not 1-1

Comment: @FelipeMora have you figure out the solution? I am new in backpack

Answer (score 0):

Example:
In Users Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
/**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}
```

If you want get one user you can try:

```
User::find(1)->phone
```

If you want get all users with phone of this user you can try

```
User::with('phone')->all();
```

After you see result object and let see it

Comment: Thank you tan, this is the normal way, but in my request i say that i am using  backpack